# Funny software metrics that have a relevant value

Tags: metrics

As a software developer, I've seen lot of different software metrics, mainly about code quality and bug-tracking.

I have heard of a "Dilbert metric", which is "how many people read and laugh at Dilbert comics in your team", which shows how bad your company/organization is.

There is also the "WTF per minute" during code reviews : http://www.osnews.com/images/comics/wtfm.jpg.

I'm looking for metrics that are both funny AND still relevant, do you have any ?

Answer (score 5):

- Programmers/salespeople ratio

Once heard a [funny | relevant] joke about SAP:

```
  _------------------------_
 /          SAP AG          \
/                            \
|____________________________|
|----------------------------|
| Etage 3:       Sales       |
|----------------------------|
| Etage 2:       Sales       |
|----------------------------|
| Etage 1:       Sales       |
|----------------------------|
| Groundfloor:   Sales       |
|____________________________|
|----------------------------|
| Underground 1: Car parking |
|----------------------------|
| Underground 2: Development |
|____________________________|
```